# Remove groups if all NA

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have a table like so:

```
df <- data.frame("Group" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
              "Num" = c(1,2,3,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA))

  Group Num
1     A   1
2     A   2
3     A   3
4     B   1
5     B   2
6     B  NA
7     C  NA
8     C  NA
9     C  NA
```

In this case, because group C has `Num` as `NA` for all entries, I would like to remove rows in group C from the table. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `group_by` on you Group and `filter` the groups with `all` values that are NA. You can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(!all(is.na(Num)))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#> # Groups:   Group [2]
#>   Group   Num
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1
#> 2 A         2
#> 3 A         3
#> 4 B         1
#> 5 B         2
#> 6 B        NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could index based on all the groups that have at least one non-NA value:

```
idx <- df$Group %in% unique(df[!is.na(df$Num),"Group"])
idx 
df[idx,]

# or in one line

df[df$Group %in% unique(df[!is.na(df$Num),"Group"]),]
```

output

```
  Group Num
1     A   1
2     A   2
3     A   3
4     B   1
5     B   2
6     B  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ave`.

```
df[with(df, !ave(Num, Group, FUN=\(x) all(is.na(x)))), ]
#   Group Num
# 1     A   1
# 2     A   2
# 3     A   3
# 4     B   1
# 5     B   2
# 6     B  NA
```